# When can I safely set constraints on on a tableHeaderView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

When I've run `tableView.tableHeaderView = myView`, I've seen that `myView` is immediately added to a superview, meaning I can safely set constraints on it. Is that guaranteed to be true, or are there times where I need to wait a bit (e.g. `DispatchQueue.async`) before setting constraints?

Comment: I'm curious why you are specifically asking about a view used as a table view header. What's special about this view that prompts this question?

Comment: This is a question about the `tableHeaderView` setter, if it always adds the subview immediately

Comment: You could setup the constraints inside the custom view's `didMoveToSuperview` method (just make sure `superview` is not `nil`).